# Entity to View Model Serialize in Framework Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a view model for a Customer entity in EF. My question is if I'm using the correct approach. I convert an entity property to a view model property. And, if what I need to return is a list I convert the properties for each object.
Is there a better way to do this serialization? I'm not asking about if convert an entity to a model is the correct approach. I'm not doing that, I just return what is needed. What I want to know is if is there a better way to serialize the entity to an object in a view model.

This is my view model:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int CUSTOMER_KEY { get; set; }
    public decimal CCUSTID { get; set; }
    public string CCNAME { get; set; }
    public string ACCNOTES { get; set; }
    public string CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LASTMODIFIEDDATE { get; set; }
    public string LASTMODIFIEDBY { get; set; }


    public static Customer FromModelToEntity(CustomerModel model)
    {
        Customer entity = new Customer();
        entity.CUSTOMER_KEY = model.CUSTOMER_KEY;
        entity.CCUSTID = model.CCUSTID;
        entity.CCNAME = model.CCNAME != null ? model.CCNAME : null;
        entity.ACCNOTES = model.ACCNOTES != null ? model.ACCNOTES : null;
        entity.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE = model.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE != null ? model.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE : null;           

        entity.LASTMODIFIEDDATE = model.LASTMODIFIEDDATE;
        entity.LASTMODIFIEDBY = model.LASTMODIFIEDBY != null ? model.LASTMODIFIEDBY : null;

        return entity;
    }

    public static CustomerModel FromEntityToModel(Customer entity)
    {
        CustomerModel model = new CustomerModel();
        model.CUSTOMER_KEY = entity.CUSTOMER_KEY;
        model.CCUSTID = entity.CCUSTID;
        model.CCNAME = entity.CCNAME != null ? entity.CCNAME : null;
        model.ACCNOTES = entity.ACCNOTES != null ? entity.ACCNOTES : null;
        model.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE = entity.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE != null ? entity.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE : null;
        model.CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE_Name = entity.CustomerPricingLevel != null ? entity.CustomerPricingLevel.DESCRIPTION : string.Empty;

        model.LASTMODIFIEDDATE = entity.LASTMODIFIEDDATE;
        model.LASTMODIFIEDBY = entity.LASTMODIFIEDBY != null ? entity.LASTMODIFIEDBY : null;

        return model;
    }

    public static List<Customer> FromModelToEntity(List<CustomerModel> modelList)
    {
        List<Customer> entityList = new List<Customer>();
        foreach (var item in modelList)
        {
            entityList.Add(CustomerModel.FromModelToEntity(item));
        }
        return entityList;
    }

    public static List<CustomerModel> FromEntityToModel(List<Customer> entityList)
    {
        List<CustomerModel> modelList = new List<CustomerModel>();
        foreach (var item in entityList)
        {
            modelList.Add(CustomerModel.FromEntityToModel(item));
        }
        return modelList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at automapper, and I would recommend separating the Domain object and the view model.  They need to be able to evolve seperatly

Comment: What do you mean with separate the domain object and the view model? From where would I get the data? Do you have a link explain that?

Comment: Having a method inside the `CustomerModel` called `FromEntityToModel` which returns a `CustomerModel` tightly coupled your `Customer` domain object and your `CustomerViewModel`. A view model is used to represent the domain in a specific way which a view expects it to be, it should not be a 1:1 representation, if it is you could just as well use the `Domain` object in the view

Comment: i don't get the evolve separately thing either.. "coupling" your model to your domain object means you'll catch any errors that might arise from database changes.  The minute you make `LASTMODIFIEDDATE` a nullable datetime in your entity model you catch the error..  Automapper will let you know after you publish and try to run your app.. or it might just ignore the field altogether.

Comment: It is not 1:1 representation I clarify that on the description of the question.  That model will grow with properties that aren't in the entity.

Comment: My question is what is the best approach to create a view model that will use properties from the entity and others not from the entity (in the future will return the customer name + random number)  needed in the view. And the entity corresponding to the CUSTPRCLEVEL_CODE which is a pk to a customer level object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what sort of answer you are seeking.

You can shorten your code using LINQ though. (System.Linq)

Insead of the foreach, you can use a 1 liner:

So that this:

```
public static List<Customer> FromModelToEntity(List<CustomerModel> modelList)
{
    List<Customer> entityList = new List<Customer>();
    foreach (var item in modelList)
    {
      entityList.Add(CustomerModel.FromModelToEntity(item));
    }
    return entityList;
}
```

Turns into this:

```
public static List<Customer> FromModelToEntity(List<CustomerModel> modelList)
{
   return modelList.Select(item => FromModelToEntity(item)).ToList();
}
```